# Running a single macro on several Cells

Tags: vba

i have written a macro which inserts few rows and then coverts text present in one cell which are separated by delimiters from texts to columns and then transposes it and gets copied as rows doing paste special which were inserted first. i can run the macro on only one cell to get the result. but now i want to run the macro on other 50 cells. how can i do it ??

My Code is below

```
Sub Newsroom()
'
' Macro
' By Ganesh
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+G
'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=True, FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7 _
        , 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array _
        (14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(21, -1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ALLNEWSPLUS"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=11).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(-21, -2).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:B22"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:B22").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without re-writing all of your code (you should get rid of `Selection` and `ActiveCell` references in favor of more object-oriented programming), you need to implement a Loop.

Assuming you initially select the range of cells (1 column) over which you want to operate:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim r as Long
    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

    For r = rng.Cells.Count to 1 Step -1
        rng.Cells(r).Select

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' ALL OF YOUR CODE BELONGS HERE
        '
        '
        '
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your inputs, but i m confused as i am new to VBA, Could you please let me know where shall I replace the above code in the previous code.

Comment: @user2800680 what is not clear about this example?   The code I provide should bracket *all* of your code. In the placeholder I have revised (it says "ALL OF YOUR CODE BELONGS HERE") is where you should put *all* of your existing code.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you very much for the quick response... Appreciate it all.. i got the desired result.