# running a macro on different cells

Tags: vba

i want to run the macro on cells like D2.... taking D2 as the active cell..
Can i run the macro on all the cells at once to get the result..  with the below code i can run the macro on only one cell

```
Sub Allocation()

'
' Allocation Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=True, FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -3).Range("A1:C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:C16"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:C16").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: This question is nearly identical to the question you asked on September 20 : [Running a single macro on several Cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925855/running-a-single-macro-on-several-cells)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what you're after, but this will loop through a range of cells selected at the beginning:

```
Sub Allocation()

'
' Allocation Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
Dim r As Range, c
Set r = Selection
For c = 1 To r.Count
    r(c).Select
      Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=True, FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Selection.Copy
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
          False, Transpose:=True
      ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -3).Range("A1:C1").Select
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:C16"), Type:= _
          xlFillDefault
      ActiveCell.Range("A1:C16").Select
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Selection.ClearContents
Next
End Sub
```